# Too many redirects for subdirectory excluded from SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I have a subdirectory /blog/ served from reverse proxy. The rest of the site is served over https.

I'm trying to get the /blog/ served over http without ssl but I keep getting too_many_redirects errors. Here is the config (edit, it worked in the past but since I did a SSL update something change somewhere - maybe with Forge - idk but don't think it matters to find solution):

```
# FORGE CONFIG
include forge-conf/example.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /blog {
        proxy_set_header X-Original-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Is-Reverse-Proxy "true";
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
        proxy_cookie_path / /blog/;
        proxy_pass http://blog.example.com/;
        expires off;
    }
    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/example.com/server/*;

    location / {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name .example.com;
    root /home/forge/example.com/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/166494/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/166494/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location /blog {
         return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
    }
    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/example.com/server/*;
```

If I add the reverse proxy block in the 443 listen part it serves correctly over https - but I can't have it like that because of mixed content (original server being http for the blog)

Edit: More info, here is the setup - not ideal but no choice: blog.example.com is hosted on apache on a different server that doesn't have SSL. example.com/blog/ serves in reverse proxy the blog located blog.example.com. example.com has an SSL certificate. I don't want to serve the blog over https otherwise I need another certificate for blog.example.com

Comment: You need to state your end goal more clearly, right now I have no idea what you're trying to achieve. Why wouldn't you want to serve the blog as https://example.com/blog ? proxying the blog won't work well as static resources are still on the other domain. Take a step back and explain things properly.

Comment: not sure what's not clear sorry. I want to serve it there /blog/. I just can't host it on this server that's why it's reverse proxied. My goal is simply to have example.com/blog/ served without https. Thanks :)

Comment: So you're saying with the configuration above it's serving properly on https, but not on http? Based on the config above it should be forwarding all https requests to http, and http should be serving them just fine. You really need to demonstrate this problem using "curl -i" of both URLs, to show headers.

Comment: ok thanks will do that. Yes I get too many redirects :/

Comment: Please demonstrate this redirect look using curl -i, right now what you're saying happens doesn't match what the configuration looks to be telling it to do. For example "curl -i headphonereviews.org" gives headers that include "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" and "Location: https://www.headphonereviews.org/". Include access logs that show the matching request to Nginx. Edit your question with this information. Without this information I will not reply to your question again.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Location: https://example.com/blog
Also, when it doesn't work I get this in the log [alert] 21089#0: *63 open socket #5 left in connection 5

Comment: That's not enough, it doesn't show a redirect chain. You need to edit your question to show curl doing a redirect, then curling this redirected address, maybe 3-4 loops. You need to show the matching Nginx access log entries. You're really making it difficult for people to help you.

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for helping (really!). I'm not too familiar with the server stuff tbh. When I did the curl -i this is what I got :/ Should I get more?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the blog being served from http, and a forwarder from https. Why is it like that?

First, move your blog location from the http to the https server, removing the existing blog location that does a forward.

Next, change your http server to forward everything, as below

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

I suspect there's a reason you have things set up as they are above, but you haven't clearly outlined what it is. If this solution doesn't work please edit your question to more clearly and fully explain your situation and exactly why this answer doesn't work - ideally including curl showing and redirect headers returned and matching Nginx access / error logs.

Comment: Thanks Tim for helping me figure this out!! I just edited my answer to add info. as you can read different servers one with SSL one without. Thanks!